# How to bundle all swagger files into one using Java and Maven

Tags: java, maven, openapi, swagger-2.0

I'm using Java 8, Spring Boot and Maven.

I have a big OpenAPI file (swagger 2.0 yaml), and I want to split it in multiple files.

But I want to bundle all in one file latter to import into my API Manager.

I know I can do that using the node.js command:

```
swagger-cli bundle openapi.yaml --outfile _build/openapi.yaml --type yaml
```

Reference: https://davidgarcia.dev/posts/how-to-split-open-api-spec-into-multiple-files/

**Question:**

There is a way to do that with Maven? Like some builder plugin to put in pom.xml and generate the bundle at the target folder?

Answer (score 1):

[Swagger Codegen Maven plugin](https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-codegen/tree/master/modules/swagger-codegen-maven-plugin) can bundle a multi-file OpenAPI definition into a single file. Use plugin version 2.x for OpenAPI 2.0, and version [3.x](https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-codegen/tree/3.0.0/modules/swagger-codegen-maven-plugin) for OpenAPI 3.0. Note that the 2.x and 3.x versions have different `groupId`s and slightly different config values.

Example for OpenAPI 2.0:

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>io.swagger</groupId>
    <artifactId>swagger-codegen-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.4.26</version>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <goals>
                <goal>generate</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
                <inputSpec>${project.basedir}/src/main/resources/openapi.yaml</inputSpec>

                <!-- Use 'swagger-yaml' to get resolved YAML or 'swagger' to get resolved JSON -->
                <language>swagger-yaml</language>

                <configOptions>
                    <!-- Default file name is swagger.yaml or swagger.json -->
                    <outputFile>openapi.yaml</outputFile>
                </configOptions>
            </configuration>
        </execution>
    </executions>
</plugin>
```

Example for OpenAPI 3.0:

```xml
<plugin>
    <groupId>io.swagger.codegen.v3</groupId>
    <artifactId>swagger-codegen-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>3.0.33</version>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <goals>
                <goal>generate</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
                <inputSpec>${project.basedir}/src/main/resources/openapi.yaml</inputSpec>

                <!-- Use 'openapi-yaml' to get resolved YAML or 'openapi' to get resolved JSON -->
                <language>openapi-yaml</language>

                <!-- Default is ${project.build.directory}/generated-sources/swagger -->
                <output>_build</output>

                <configOptions>
                    <!-- Default file name is openapi.yaml or openapi.json -->
                    <outputFile>openapi.yaml</outputFile>
                </configOptions>
            </configuration>
        </execution>
    </executions>
</plugin>
```

Comment: Thanks, but there is only one input yaml in your samples...

Comment: `inputSpec` is the main file that contains `$ref` references to other files.

Comment: Do you have any sample of how is the main file for the swagger 2.0?